# How to use ObservableList in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, javafx

I must use this code on my android Project but I can't find it in Android.

I google it and find there is "android.databind.ObservableArrayList" but in Android Studio I can't find it.

```
 private ObservableList<Urunler> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use `ObservableArrayList` you need to download the library from the Support repository in the Android SDK manager.

To configure your app to use data binding, add the `dataBinding` element to your build.gradle file in the app module.

Use the following code snippet to configure data binding:

```
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
```

after that you will be able to use `ObservableArrayList` in Android Studio

([read the docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html))

Answer (score 0):

The code mentioned uses JavaFx 8 API's. Make sure your IDE is using java 8 JavaFX API if not include them or update your JDK. Get a copy of JDK from the official [website](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/java8-2100321.html).

Read **FxCollections** docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html)

Read **ObservableList** docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html)

Comment: What should i use when i making android program, instead of ObservableList

Comment: since java 8 JavaFx features like ObservableList are not supported on android so you got to use something else like RXjava it has Observable class and allows asynchronous calls.