# ObservableList is missing in Android Studio?

Tags: android

I'm trying to define member property as an [ObservableList](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ObservableList) in Android Studio, but the IDE doesn't know that type.

How can I use it?

Comment: Do you have the data binding library pulled in? https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/start

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use ObservableList in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47610144/how-to-use-observablelist-in-android-studio)